# Is it healthier to lie in the bed/on the sofa or to sit on the chair in front of the desk?

Tags: spine, back, ergonomics, position, sedentary-lifestyle

I mostly stand during my job. At home I can either lie down or sit in a chair with a desk in front of me. So, is it healthier to lie in the bed/on the sofa (e.g. with laptop) or to sit on the chair in front of the desk?

My concern is mostly about keeping good posture and my spine healthy.

Comment: There's also some concerns to have with keeping your laptop above your genitals (especially for man) and possible radiation too...but i never really did a good research on this subject.